# Using commonly duplicated questions to our advantage

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Edit: To be clear, I'm not trying to solve the problem of duplicates, but as long as we have them...

If a question is commonly duplicated, I think that is an interesting property of the original question. I would like to be able to browse such common questions, possibly by adding a new "commonly-duplicated" tag. This could be useful when trying to remove duplicates, but mostly it would also be a way for people to learn answers to questions that are clearly important to many people.

Would others find this functionality useful? Or have suggestions on variations?

Comment: a commonly-duplicated tag would be redundant and people would keep on posting duplicates.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve the problem of duplicates. I'm trying to use the fact that we have duplicates to make the site more useful.

Comment: I still disagree with tagging to indicate this status (since tagging the source questions is about as harmful as tagging the duplicates), but my original proposed solution doesn't actually work. I wonder, does the data dump actually contain information on questions closed as duplicates (and by extension, the ability to retrieve the questions linked in question)?

Comment: There's meaning to this question.  If 'duplicates' are a reoccurring problem then it should be identified as something 'requiring' a solution which would not be 'educate the world' because the odds of that happening over the internet are slim to none.  Take for instance the abusive, sarcastic behavior of some posters due to their anonymity.  The answer lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It would make no difference to those folk who aren't inclined to search and we already have a vote to close as duplicate. But some folk will never learn.

And frankly, it's rep for old rope...

Answer (score 1):

We have this functionality in the form of the [Human Powered Linked Posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/) and the System Generated Related Posts.

If you're inclined to retag posts, then I'd retag duplicate questions to have the same tags as the questions they duplicate, so it's more likely to be caught in the 'Related Questions'.